# Determine both the conjunctive and disjunctive normal forms for the following expression [verification]

Tags: proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following expression:

$$ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \ \land (p_2 \to p_1)) \  \land (p_3 \leftrightarrow p_2)) $$

---

Work so far:

1) CNF:

$
\begin{align*}
&\ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (p_2 \to p_1)) \land (p_3 \leftrightarrow p_2))  & \text{(Given)} \\
\equiv &\ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (\neg p_2 \lor p_1)) \land (p_3 \leftrightarrow p_2)) & \text{(Simplification of implication)} \\
\equiv &\ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (\neg p_2 \lor p_1))  \land ((\neg p_3 \lor p_2 ) \land (p_3 \lor \neg p_2))) & \text{(Simplification of biconditional)} \\
\equiv &\ ((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (\neg p_2 \lor p_1) \land (\neg p_3 \lor p_2 ) \land (p_3 \lor \neg p_2)) & \text{(Associativity of conjunction)} \\
\end{align*}
$

Q.E.D. (Whilst the expression could further be simplified, at this point it satisfies the definition of CNF).

2) DNF:

\begin{align*}
&\ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (p_2 \to p_1)) \land (p_3 \leftrightarrow p_2))  & \text{(Given)} \\
\equiv &\ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (\neg p_2 \lor p_1)) \land (p_3 \leftrightarrow p_2)) & \text{(Simplification of implication)} \\
\equiv &\ (((p_3 \lor p_1) \land (\neg p_2 \lor p_1))  \land (( p_3 \land p_2 ) \lor (\neg p_3 \land \neg p_2))) & \text{(Simplification of biconditional)} \\
\equiv &\ ((p_1 \lor (\neg p_2 \land p_3)) \land (( p_3 \land p_2 ) \lor (\neg p_3 \land \neg p_2))) & \text{(Distribution of disjunction over conjunction)} \\
\equiv &\ ((p_1 \land ( p_3 \land p_2 )) \lor (p_1 \land (\neg p_3 \land \neg p_2)) \lor
((\neg p_2 \land p_3) \land ( p_3 \land p_2 )) \lor ((\neg p_2 \land p_3) \land (\neg p_3 \land \neg p_2))) & \text{(Distribution of conjunction over disjunction)} \\
\end{align*}

Q.E.D. (As above, sufficient albeit messy).

---

Why have I posted this question for verification?

- I am not sure if I have applied the steps correctly.
- I suspect that my approach is too verbose, and since this was taken from a practice exam where it wasn't worth many marks, I want to know if I can simplify my approach/save time anywhere. (So far the only thing I can think of is introducing shorthand terms a,b,c,d for the clauses in the final steps of each calculation, but this assumes my general approach is robust).

**Is my solution correct? Can it be improved?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are both correct.

The result for the DNF can be simplified:

$$((\neg p_2 \land p_3) \land ( p_3 \land p_2 )) \text{ and } ((\neg p_2 \land p_3) \land (\neg p_3 \land \neg p_2)))$$

are both impossible because they contain $x \land \neg x$.
Hence you could just write
$$((p_1 \land ( p_3 \land p_2 )) \lor (p_1 \land (\neg p_3 \land \neg p_2)).$$

---

There is a method which is computationally acceptable when you have few variables, such as in this case.
You write the 'truth table' (the following picture is generated using a [truth table generator](http://mrieppel.net/prog/truthtable.html)):

[image]

Then the expression is true exactly when $(p_1, p_2, p_3) = (1, 1, 1) = v_1$ or $(p_1, p_2, p_3) = (1, 0, 0) = v_4$.

Consider the formulae

$$
\begin{align}
\psi_1 &= (p_1 \land p_2 \land p_3) \\
\psi_4 &= (p_1 \land (\neg p_2) \land (\neg p_3)).
\end{align}
$$

The formula $\psi_i$ is true exactly when the truth assignment is that of $v_i$, hence the expression is equivalent to

$$(p_1 \land p_2 \land p_3) \lor (p_1 \land (\neg p_2) \land (\neg p_3))$$

as found before.

At this point you can easily find a CNF as follows

1. find a DNF for the *negation*: the expression is false exactly when $p_1$ is false or (the other two cases), hence
   $$(\neg p_1) \lor (p_1 \land (\neg p_2) \land p_3) \lor (p_1 \land p_2 \land (\neg p_3));$$
2. negate the previous expression to get the result:
   $$
     \begin{align}
     &\ p_1 \land ((\neg p_1) \lor p_2 \lor (\neg p_3)) \land ((\neg p_1) \lor (\neg p_2) \lor p_3) \\
     \equiv &\ p_1 \land (p_2 \lor (\neg p_3)) \land ((\neg p_2) \lor p_3).
     \end{align}
     $$

The results we found for the CNF are different but equivalent. I feel there is less chance to make errors with this method instead of manipulating long expressions, but this is a personal opinion.

Comment: I agree with your personal opinion, and whilst one could argue that it is subjective, I think your answer provides an extra dimension for people to think about these problems in. Thanks!